# How to fix outer/inner glow glitch in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustration

Previously I had made this artwork in 2400 x 3000 resolution, but now that I'm trying to increase the document size to 3200 x 4000, parts of the glow for a text is acting up, no matter what I do. There are sharp cuts in the glow.

Also, there is a strange cut in the inner glow of the letter C which looks like the white border around each letter (see image).

Appreciate it if you could tell me what the problem is.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Menu Effect** > **Document Raster Effects Setting**

With such large objects, if your document is a Web file/RGB colors, I think this is the case because the size is in pixels; and the effects resolution is 300 ppi, you get this:

[image: Artifact]

If your document is a Web file/RGB colors, the effects must have a screen Resolution, 72 ppi:

[image: Right]